# How to get a windows file "author" not the owner using c++ with windows api

Tags: c++, file, winapi

I found this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa446629(v=vs.85).aspx) where it shows how to get the owner of the file but is there anyway we can also get the author of the file using windows api and C++?

Comment: What, if there are more than one authors? What, if the file comes from a system, that doesn't record this information? You are asking for something that doesn't exist, and this question sounds like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/205381). What problem are you really trying to solve?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> author of the file

No such thing exists in Windows filesystems.

You might be confused by a [**descriptive metadata**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metadata) stored in some data formats, such as PDF, DOC, various image, audio and video formats.

Retrieving this metadata is obviously *format-specific* (there might be [libraries](http://mediaarea.net/tr/MediaInfo) [for](https://taglib.github.io/) [that](http://www.exiv2.org/)).

Also, metadata is optional and not all the files contain it.

Comment: Native/COM `IShellFolder2::GetDetailsOf()` can be used to retrieve what would be displayed if you added the *Authors* column to an explorer view, which as stated is file type dependent.

Comment: Yes, That was the problem. I thought its a windows feature because there is authors column which shows authors for some files.